# How to customise parental control alert in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have two accounts in my Pc. One is Administrative account and another one is normal user account which has less permissions. I set time limits for that user account using parental controls in Administrative account. When I logging on into that user account it is displaying a message like.. "Your account has time restrictions that prevent you from logging on at this time. Please try again later". Up to now everything is fine, but i want display my own custom message ...Is it possible...Please suggest me..

Thank You very much...

Comment: This is indeed possible just not with the default parental controls built into Windows.  There are lots of third-party solutins that might fit the bill.